# What's the best practice for returning an HTTP 500 error description?

Tags: rest, http, backend

I'm working on an API service and I'm having a dilemma on how to implement 500 reponses.
I'm not certain on which is best between sending the actual error cause or just a generic "internal server error" message.

The arguments I can see for each are:

1. **Explicit error description:** The cause is clear to any client consuming the API and easier feedback can be given to the API dev when the exact error cause is known.
2. **Generic error:** The underlying implementation is hidden from clients as they do not need to know how the API works behind-the-scenes. From that perspective, it could also probably be better security against malicious clients.

Which is generally seen as a better practice, and are there also other reasons to consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice would be to throw a generic error message returning as little information to the client as possible. If additional context is required for debugging purposes, you can write that context to a server-side log.

For example, in C#:

```
try
{
    // Do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error("Error details", ex);
    return StatusCode(500, "Something went wrong");
}
```

Remember to obfuscate any confidential information (like passwords) if you log to the server; you should log *just* enough relevant information to diagnose and resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to be the best of both worlds as the client can always communicate the time the error occured to the API dev if they need to.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted if no other convincing perspective is brought up.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I take with this (in Node.js) is as follows:

1. Uncaught errors get turned into `InternalServerError`. exceptions.
2. We have a middleware that turns this into the standard `application/problem+json` error response.
3. In dev/testing, the error response contains the message from the thrown error.
4. In prod, this gets turned into a generic error message that leaks no information about internals.
5. In all of cases we log the real message.
6. In some system I've built we emitted an 'id' in the error response corresponding to an id in the log, making it easier for someone to report a problem and us to look up related information.

Comment: Thanks. The pattern of different messages between the dev and production environments is quite an interesting approach. 
Something worth considering.